# Installing PostgreSQL on CentOS 7 (since mid April 2020)

Tags: postgresql

I have a script that I use for installing Postgres 9.6 in a CentOS 7 Docker image. It looks like this:

```
wget https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm
yum install -y -q pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm epel-release
yum update -y -q
yum install -y -q postgresql96-server sudo
```

As of mid April 2020, it started failing because `https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm` is no longer available. I understand that the way RPM packages for Postgres are published has changed this month. Can anyone help me find the updated url for the 9.6 rpm package? I have been Googling but can't seem to find it for some reason.

Really appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

The new repository URL is available here: https://www.postgresql.org/download/

1. Select Redhat/Centos 7
2. Select version 9.6

Then it shows you how to install the new repository:

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```